# Get items between two values in an np.array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, element, numpy-ndarray

I'm new to Phython and was wondering if anyone can help me with this exercise:
I have an array in python and I want to get the elements that have values between 5 and 10.

```
a = np.array([2, 6, 1, 9, 10, 3, 27])
```

The exercise asks me to do this in three different ways and gives me the "hint" to use the & operator and np.logical_and() function.

Can anyone please help me out? Thanks!

Comment: better example would have been a = np.array([2, 6, 1, 9, 10, 3, 27, 8])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ≥5 and <10, you can use slicing:

```
a[(a>=5) & (a<10)]
```

or

```
a[np.logical_and(a>=5, a<10)]
```

output: `array([6, 9])`